# Cannot Remove Password on Windows 10 Account

Tags: passwords, windows-10-preview

I am having an issue with removing a password from my account on Windows 10. The account is currently password protected, but I do not want it to be. To resolve this, I attempted to use the "Settings" app, but doing so resulted in the following error.

[image]

As this is my personal computer and I am administrator, I have full access to the computer's policy settings. Here are the settings I have for password-related settings.

[image: Password-Related Policy Settings]

Why am I still unable to remove my password completely? I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 build 10240.

Comment: If you suspect this to be a bug you should report it.  This user connected to a Microsoft Account by chance?  Your current displayed settings are identical to a virtual machine I have, of 10240, and I don't have this problem.  What do you mean exactly by "removing" a password?

Comment: This is a local account. The account previously had no password, then I accidentally made it a Microsoft Account. I have since undone that setting, but I cannot remove my password. By removing my password, I mean setting the password to be blank so that it is not protected. I suspected that it was a bug, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: If you give me a minute to create a snapshot.  I will test it, because my local account with no password was connected to a Microsoft Account also, I can test easily enough.  Only problem I have is I have a pin connected to the account, which I can't seem to remove, but thats a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you. I've also noticed that booting up is very slow. My screen goes black for at least a whole minute at times.

Comment: You should run the DISM and SFC tools.  The behavior you describe is suspect.

Comment: I did the following.  Logged into my Microsoft Account connected account, switched to a local account with no password, I then logged into the local account without a password with no problems.  This isn't a bug.  I don't sync my settings, if you do, you might be running into a conflict situation.  I also created when i created this vm, the local account, then linked it to a MA.

Comment: Thanks! Would those tools fix the problem for sure?

Comment: The only way to find out is to run them.

Comment: @Ramhound Very well. I ran in to numerous other issues as well, so for now, I opted to roll back to Windows 8.1 and try the upgrade again. Hopefully it resolves the issue, although if it doesn't, at least I know of a few possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by HP ProtectTools, which requires a password on the user account in order to operate properly. It appears that after adding a password to an account that did not previously have one, it is impossible to remove the password thanks to this software. Removing the software from the computer resolves the issue.

Comment: In my case it was `HP Client Security`

Comment: @Madhur As far as I am aware, HP Client Security is a rebranded version of HP ProtectTools.

**Update:** [It looks like I was right.](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/HP-ProtectTools-Security-Manager-and-Windows-10/td-p/5186560)